# Set window larger than screen size

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript

Is it possible to set the window size larger than the screen size? I open TextEdit for example and I use the following:

```
set bounds of window 1 to {10, 10, 400, 2200}
```

But the height never reaches the `2200` mark. It is limited to the screen size. I am hoping I can force the height past the screen size so that I can screenshot full length windows.

Happy to try other languages that this will work in. Maybe objective-c, Cocoa application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface MyDelegate : NSObject
{
  NSWindow *myWindow;
}
- (void) createMenu;
- (void) createWindow;
- (void) applicationWillFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)not;
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)not;
@end

@implementation MyDelegate : NSObject 
- (void) dealloc
{
  [myWindow release];
}

- (void) createMenu
{
  NSMenu *menu;

  menu = [[NSMenu new] autorelease];

  [menu addItemWithTitle: @"Quit"  
        action: @selector (terminate:)  
        keyEquivalent: @"q"];

  [NSApp setMainMenu: menu];
}

- (void) createWindow
{
  NSRect rect = NSMakeRect (100, 100, 2000, 2000);
  unsigned int styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask 
                           | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask;


  myWindow = [NSWindow alloc];
  myWindow = [myWindow initWithContentRect: rect
                       styleMask: styleMask
                       backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered
                       defer: NO];
  [myWindow setTitle: @"This is a test window"];
}

- (void) applicationWillFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)not
{
  [self createMenu];
  [self createWindow];
}

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)not;
{
  [myWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];
}
@end

int main (int argc, const char **argv)
{ 
  [NSApplication sharedApplication];
  [NSApp setDelegate: [MyDelegate new]];

  return NSApplicationMain (argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: Will this work for the TextEdit app? I am not creating my own windows - I am launching apps that have windows. Please see my comment to Oliver.

Comment: Note that any NSWindow with a title bar automatically constrains itself to the screen(from Window Programming Guide).

Comment: I am not using a NSWindow and I don't have that level of control of windows - as I mentioned previously. i am opening other applications and trying to increase the window height out of the screen.

Comment: Btw, your code doesn't work. Is it a Cocoa application? It only runs when I remove the main but the window size is 2000 by 2000.

Comment: Yes it is cocoa application and its working fine on my system.

Comment: I am on snow leopard - any special frameworks required or settings or just the standard stuff? Can the code be simplified any further?

Comment: I am also on snow leopard. its normal cocoa application. you can remove menu function.

Comment: Download code  
Link: http://www2.ibackup.com/qmanager/ibsjsp/IBSGetShare.jsp?key=qhrgh08944

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do that ? If you want to display something that is bigger than the window, you have the UIScrollView for that :

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Use it and adjust it's contentSize to {10, 10, 400, 2200}.
And you're done.

Comment: This isn't a window created by me. This window belongs to another application. For example the `TextEdit` app, I open it up and set the window size. However, I want to make it big enough so that I can capture the window as an image. Everything works but I can't seem to find a way to make the window large enough.

Comment: @Abs : you could perhaps try to adjust its view/subviews size instead of the window size ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Oliver - how would I do that? Is there something in applescript to target this?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the nib files and set a different minimum size for the windows. Applications set minimum sizes for their windows in order to prevent autoresizing problems, which can make some views disappear and do not show up when the window size is enlarged. From what I’ve gathered, it looks like you cannot query or set the minimum size from AppleScript.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770271/how-to-get-and-or-overwrite-the-minimum-size-of-windows-in-mac-osx) is a question similar to yours, an answer was never found but the comments on the question were just as good as answers.